# Transfering and using a Matlab inline function to a c++ mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, function, mex

I am trying to generate a mex file for a c++ library, so that i can call its methods directly from matlab.

As my first argument I want to transfer an inline function, for example `inline('sin(x)+3')`.

But now I want to use this function dynamically in my c++ program. There is no method like mxGetInlineFunction(), right? Is there a way I can get my inline item from the array and use it as a math-function in my c++ code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

use [`mexCallMATLAB()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html) and [`mexCallMATLABWithTrap()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlabwithtrap.html)

Comment: This would use Matlab to evaluate the expression. But I need the inline function as an argument for another c++ function like doStuff(function)

Comment: Use an Anonymous Function instead of  `inline`, call it with `feval()` via `mexCallMATLAB()`

Comment: Same here. I explicitly don't want Matlab to compute the function. I just want to get a function somehow from Matlab to C++.

Comment: `'sin(x)+3'` is a string, at execution time you'll need a math parser for C++ to do the work, ie https://fastmathparser.codeplex.com/. Calling LUA or  python might also do the work, But if you're using mex, what's the reason for not using MATLAB?

Comment: I want to use c++ to save some time while my intensive calculations. When I give those calculations back to Matlab, I save no time at all. I want to compare the time of Matlab and the c++ execution.

Comment: so you want to compare the c++ implementation of the inline function with the one from matlab? But you do not want to implement the inline function explicitly in c++, cause you want to compared multiple different functions.

Comment: That sounds like one of my use cases, yes.

Comment: I too wish to implement algorithms in Matlab and just get c++ of them for free. [Matlab Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) kind of does that with some extra catches, it is also a separate package and the generated code is not always readable. My advice for any function that you write in matlab in 'straigh-forward' (for-loops etc) way it will be faster in C++. For function with vectorization it becomes more tricky and the difference might be small but it **depends** a lot on the function.